# How to find element of username field using selenium driver

Tags: selenium

i'm trying to find the username element with webdriver.
the webpage is developped with polymer
the html content is:

```
<gui-input class="flex style-scope login-window x-scope gui-input-0" id="username" icon="account-circle" label="Username" autofocus="" floating-label="">
```

With Selenium i tried this :

```
driver.findElement(By.className("gui-input#username")).isDisplayed()
```

But it cannot find the username field.

Any help please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By class name locator expects a *class name*, but you are passing in a CSS selector.

Instead, use a "by CSS selector" locator:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("gui-input#username"))
```

or "by id":

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username"))
```

Comment: when i try with id or cssselector i have this error message: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.110)

Comment: @TemplogLog my guess is that there is an another element with the same id which is invisible - check that. Please provide a link to the webpage you are working with if possible, or the complete HTML of the page. Thanks.

Comment: it ' s too big, i cannot put online the html page

Comment: i found with selenium builder